# Object Mapping to the Root Json return nil

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I need to map the following Json with AlamofireObjectMapper:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Dealer",
    "last_name": "Seller",
    "email": "seller@winfooz.com",
    "authentication_token": "L6HzhZWdWhtxNwVkrsjY",
    "documents_uploaded": false,
    "type": "Dealer"
  }
}
```

I wrote the following part of code, but the mapped object return nil!

```
class SystemUser:Mappable{       
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        type <- map[SystemUserIdentifiers.UserType] //"type"
        firstName <- map[SystemUserIdentifiers.FirstName]
        lastName <- map[SystemUserIdentifiers.LastName]
        internalIdentifier <- map[SystemUserIdentifiers.InternalIdentifier]
        email <- map[SystemUserIdentifiers.Email]
        documentsUploaded <- map[SystemUserIdentifiers.DocumentsUploaded]
        authenticationToken <- map[SystemUserIdentifiers.AuthenticationToken]
    }
}
```

Here is sending the post request:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, URL, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).responseObject {
            (response: Response<SystemUser, NSError>) in

guard let user = response.result.value else{
                return
            }
print(user.authenticationToken)
}
```

What is the correct way to map rooted Json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to make two mappable objects; one for response and another one for user; like

```
//Response
class ServerResponse:Mappable{
    var user: SystemUser?       
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        user <- map["user"]
    }
}
```

-

```
//User class
class SystemUser:Mappable{
    var type:String?
    var firstName:String?
    var lastName:String?
    // ... Further properties

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        type <- map["type"] //"type"
        firstName <- map["first_name"]
        lastName <- map["last_name"]
        // ... Further properties
    }
}
```

and now

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, URL, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).responseObject {
            (response: Response<ServerResponse, NSError>) in
    print(response.user?.authenticationToken) 

   //Do your work here


}
```

Another option is that you ask backend developer to remove that user key and send data in single dictionary